# Aggregate single column in R

Tags: r, variables, aggregate

I have some data with only one variable, as following:

```
dd <- data.frame (
  x=sample (1:10, 100, T)
)
```

I want to aggregate, for example count each occurance, but only with base package's functions

```
dd |>
  transform(y=1) |>
  do(aggregate(y~x, data=., FUN = \(x) length(x)))
```

is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
as.data.frame(table(dd))
   dd Freq
1   1   11
2   2   10
3   3   13
4   4    8
5   5   13
6   6    9
7   7    6
8   8   10
9   9   10
10 10   10
```